# finding the path to a file residing in the wamp www directory

Tags: php, wampserver

I have a file which is in project folder my wampserver www directory and I want to create a path to this file in my PHP script. I am not sure what is right in accomplishing this as I have seen the use of "./", "../" and the full root directory of "c:/...." I foresee a situation where the use of C: would restrict the usage of the path to only that local machine and I therefore want to use the wamp's root which is www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the document root just read it from the [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)-superglobal.

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Comment: So I could do something like: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].folder/filename; I checked my php.ini, the doc_root is empty does this affect anything? thanks

Comment: Its usually set by the server, if php is not runnig as cgi.